# AngularJS using value in value (constant)

Tags: angularjs

I want to know if it is possible to use another value defining value in Angular? Let's say I have two defined values and want to define third value using first two:

```
angular.module('my.module').value('firstOne', ['John', 'Mary']);
angular.module('my.module').value('secondOne', ['Tom', 'Jack']);

angular.module('my.module').value('combined', [firstOne[0], secondOne[1]);
```

Comment: As there is no way to inject anything into a value I'm guessing the answer is no.

Comment: It is possible to use a "value" to define another "value". Also, if you want to change it within your code at some point, use `value`, if not, use `constant`. Follow the explanation: http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/

Comment: @klauskpm can you write example of it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this,

```
var app = angular.module('my.module', []); //just a shortcut, don't have to do this

app.value('firstOne', ['John', 'Mary']);
app.value('secondOne', ['Tom', 'Jack']);

app.service('constantService', function(firstOne, secondOne) {
  this.combined = [firstOne[0], secondOne[1]];
});
```

then use it anywhere as inject constantService in the function, and then call
constantService.combined

Comment: That is pretty much what I have been thinking, if there will be no other answers I will accept this one

Comment: He can also declare `combined` as `app.value('combined', []);` call it on `function` and finish like `combined.push([firstOne[0], secondOne[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

we can done your task by doing below code.

```
angular.module('my.module')
.value('RESOURCES', (function() {
 var firstOne = ['John', 'Mary'];
 var secondOne = ['Tom', 'Jack'];
 return {
   firstOne: firstOne,
   secondOne: firstOne,
   combined: firstOne[0] + firstOne[1]
}
})())
```